# Why 'People' columns are not available for Read-Only users in SharePoint Datasheet view?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, datasheet

I can see columns that list people names in SharePoint's datasheet view, but read-only users cannot.

Is there a way for read-only users to see columns of this type?
The type of information in this column is: Person or Group, no mandatory information, allow multiple selections, People only, choose from All users, show field - name with presence.

Comment: I've tested this with a user in the Restricted Read group and can't reproduce the problem. Do you have more details about how the column was set and group the read-only users are in? Please update the question with that information.

Comment: The type of information in this column is: Person or Group, no mandatory information, allow multiple selections, People only, choose from All users, show field - name with presence. This is how was set up.

Comment: We also tried this with a test user and it worked, but for some reason the real people using the list can't see these columns. I can because I have admin rights, but they do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Kevin and I work on SharePoint

What's likely happening is that the read-only user doesn't have access to the user info list where this information is stored.

Comment: The user info is from our outlook address repository, so they all should have access.

Comment: Hi Kevin,
All users are stored in the same database, I can see everything, so can they, exept for these columns in SharePoint. We tried with a Test user and it worked, but it did not with real people.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue as well.  Confirm the version of Office that the users have.  I believe an Office '07 DLL is required for Datasheet View to work reliably.

Regards,

Comment: I had Office '03, now on '07.